# Does antimatter really exist and is it a given in the scientific community?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity

Antimatter erases ordinary matter when it meets, that is, it cannot be found on planet Earth. Can Karl Anderson’s experiment be disproved about his alleged discovery of the existence of antimatter? Is it really a given and no one doubts that it does not exist at all?

Comment: I mean, it has been created in a lab (e.g. CERN) - is that not enough evidence for you?

Comment: I do not mean its production, but rather its discovery that its production on earth is possible, but for you to discover it in cosmic rays, I do not think that it is true.

Comment: I do not understand your reasoning, creation of antimatter on earth does not count as a proof, but if it comes from space it does?

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page detailing this subject and I am at a loss to know why you think antimatter might not exist.  Questions about non-mainstream physics is off-topic here and disproving the existence of antimatter certainly is not mainstream..

Comment: @Wolphram jonny Antimatter annihilates when it meets ordinary matter, and when it enters the atmosphere, antimatter will disappear, so how can it be detected from space

Comment: This might help - [Why This Stuff Costs $2700 Trillion Per Gram - Antimatter at CERN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCuyCJocJWg)

Comment: You did not get my point, why creating it on earth does not satisfy your standards as a proof. What would it be the difference if it came from space? why would you accept it as a proof if it was detected in space?

Comment: @Redbel it doesn't disappear immediately, and when it annhilates it produces photons of very specific wavelengths. I work with a team that has personally detected positrons create by radiation in thunderstorms in hurricane patricia 2015

Comment: This is silly. Of course it exists. We use it all the time in medical imaging: **Positron Emission Tomography**. The antimatter (positron) is in the name. You can have a positron emitter shipped to your PET scanner in less than an hour, and inject it in patients minutes after that. It is done thousands of times per day all over the world

Comment: I think it's worth noting that there isn't really a fundamental difference between antimatter and "ordinary" matter. The labels of antimatter and matter are somewhat arbitrary, particularly with regards to particles which are their own antiparticles, like photons and Z bosons.

Answer (score 3):

> Antimatter erases ordinary matter when it meets, that is, it cannot be found on planet Earth.

It appears that antimatter doesn't exist in any significant quantity anywhere within our observable universe.  But it is created in smaller amounts constantly.  Radioactive decay of elements on earth, lightning, cosmic ray impacts, and particle accelerators all produce small but detectable quantities.

> Can Karl Anderson’s experiment be disproved about his alleged discovery of the existence of antimatter?

Experiments aren't normally "disproved", but either dismissed due to poor or flawed design, or the implications of them are reevaluated due to changes in the theory that they speak to.  Neither of these are necessary here.  The idea of how antimatter "works" in our universe is a core part of physics including the standard model.  Removing those initial experiments would have no effect on our current models.

> Is it really a given and no one doubts that it does not exist at all?

In as much as all physical theories are provisional on current evidence and current theories, yes.  Antimatter as a concept is core to our understanding of certain areas of physics.  Some other concept would be required to do a better job of explaining decades of physical experiments to remove it as an idea.  At the moment, there is no controversy or alternative explanation with any amount of support.

> Antimatter annihilates when it meets ordinary matter, and when it enters the atmosphere, antimatter will disappear, so how can it be detected from space

The annihilation proceeds due to physical rules.  As such the products of this interaction are a very strong signal to the event.  We see the same signatures in outer space as we do in laboratories.  When we see skid marks, a detached wheel, shattered glass, and crumpled chassis on a road, we don't have to ask hard questions to determine that an automobile collision has occurred.  We can do the same with the products of annihilation events.

Answer (score 3):

> Antimatter erases ordinary matter when it meets, that is, it cannot be found on planet Earth.

As an example, when an electron and a positron collide into each other, the result is energy in the form of light. That is, $$e^- + e^+ \rightarrow \gamma + \gamma$$ This can also happen for other particle/antiparticle pairs.

> it cannot be found on planet Earth.

The existence of antimatter, which was first theorized by Paul Dirac in 1928, was actually discovered in the form of positrons by Carl Anderson in 1932 as you have described.

These positrons occur naturally in radioactive processes on earth, for example, the [beta decay of Potassium-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium-40). The fact that antimatter will immediately annihilate (when it meets matter), does not mean that antimatter does not exist on earth, but perhaps has more to do with the fact that  [there is far more matter than antimatter](https://home.cern/science/physics/matter-antimatter-asymmetry-problem), and the reason for this is a topic of major research. This matter/antimatter asymmetry is universal and not limited to earth.

> Is it really a given and no one doubts that it does not exist at all?

It is accepted by every physicist that antimatter or antiparticles do indeed exist. This is because we have empirical, experimental evidence for its existence, and it would be very unusual that any scientist would deny its existence.

To show evidence that antimatter does not exist, one would need to formulate a consistent theory, that explains our observations in terms of something *other* than antiparticles, and then verify this experimentally. To me, and many others on this site, and worldwide, the success of such a theory is very unlikely, since our theories that do describe antiparticles, namely [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), is so astonishingly, almost miraculously, accurate in its predictions.